# How to compile RRDTool on Windows/ Strawberry

Tags: windows, perl, rrd

This question follows [How to install RRDTool::OO on Strawberry perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944526/how-to-install-rrdtooloo-on-strawberry-perl/8946909#8946909) 
I thought it would be better to create a new question, for the sake of clarity.

Resume:

One wants to install the RRDTool::OO perl library on Windows. To do that, the library RRDTool is required. It is a C lib and must be compiled manually. 
First thing to be compiled is the rrd.sln project. This runs smoothly with visual C++
Second thing to do is to compile RRDs.XS. This doesn't work at all with Strawberry perl.

1) I launched `perl ntmake-build` to generate a makefile for windows.
2) Then launched dmake to compile the module. A bunch of compilation error is displayed.

Issues come from the fact that the ntmake-build file use statics path that are not right for Strawberry perl. But even after having correcting them, errors are still thrown:

RRDs.o:RRDs.c:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to `rrd_clear_error'

RRDs.o:RRDs.c:(.text+0x985): undefined reference to `rrd_restore'

RRDs.o:RRDs.c:(.text+0x9f7): undefined reference to `rrd_test_error'

RRDs.o:RRDs.c:(.text+0xafd): undefined reference to `rrd_clear_error'

......................

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\RRDs\RRDs.dll'

Does someone has ever compiled this module on windows/Strawberry?

Comment: You say you launched dmake to compile the module, but the README instructs you to run nmake. Is this a typo or did you maybe just try to compile it with the wrong compiler?

Comment: it's not a typo, dmake is the make* util that's shipped with Strawberry perl. I guess nmake comes with ActiveState Perl?. The C compiler used is MinGW.

Comment: It says nmake, because that's the make Visual C++ uses, which you need to compile this with.

Comment: I tried to use the absolute path of the executable for nmake, but another error is triggered: syntax error at -e line 1, near "'755')
"
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe' : code retour '0xff'
Stop.

Comment: So I guess that the makefile generated by ntmake-build is wrong for nmake...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible - or complicated due to several hacks to create and apply to the library - to compile RRDs.XS on windows server 2008 64 bits edition. Here are several points:

- There is no PPM package for RRDTool (at least on the ActiveState repositories).
- Anyway, Strawberry perl x64 does not embed a PPM tool.
- The RRDTools makefiles are written for an AS 32 bits installation (mainly due to the static path for perl libraries, maybe I missed other static path - for C libraries for example).

Those are the main points I can list, that avoid a clean installation of RRDTool on Strawberry Perl.
This means that the frontend module RRDTool::OO can also not be used.

Comment: "Strawberry perl x64" Even on a 64 bit operating system you would use a 32 bit Perl. I don't really want to explain it now, so suffice it to say, that you only need the 64 bit perl if you want to operate on REALLY big numbers.

Comment: Ok I guess I understand. I'm going try again with the 32bits version of Strawberry. I think that the issues are mainly related to the compiler used by Strawberry (minGW, that is, gcc. Use the Visual C++ compiler will be more helpful).

Comment: Very likely that that will help too. Good luck. :)